# Jekyll adding Null Characters to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby, vagrant, jekyll

I'm trying to use [this theme](https://github.com/CloudCannon/Strata-Jekyll-Theme) with Jekyll. However, my generated JavaScript has illegal characters appended to it, causing errors when the page is rendered.

In particular `js/init.js` seems to have two characters added to the end of it once rendered into `_site`. In Sublime Text they show as `NUL`, and in vi they show as `^@`.

I'm running Jekyll from a Trusty Vagrant VM, and the source repo is a mapped volume to my Windows host. I've not edited any of the files at this point, so I can't see it being anything to do with line endings.

Any ideas?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my Ubuntu 14.04. Can you push your code on a github repository ? We'll first investigate code editor glitches. Things like encoding (utf-8) and no BOM...

Comment: Thanks for getting in touch. Editing the files in vi on the Trusty guest seems to not cause the issue. I'll try and get the Vagrant file and site into a repo for testing.

Comment: Having the same issue. Sometimes it adds nul characters, and sometimes it saves the file only half way. Any idea whats causing it? I am also on Ubuntu 14 through Vagrant, editing with Sublime on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

(Following up to a super-old question, I know.)

TL;DR: **Solution**: *apply frontmatter to the Javascript file*.

I kept running into this issue, over the course of a few months, and turned up no solutions in search. Finally today, I think I've resolved my own case of it...

It turns out Jekyll is trying to process that file (at least it appears in my case) as a page document, so it looks for the frontmatter, and for some reason fails to render the file when it's missing.

After adding some frontmatter to my script, even though it breaks Javascript compatibility for the file on its own, Jekyll seems to play nice with it, and I'm no longer seeing the trailing `^@` characters (etc).

**Sample script with frontmatter**

This tactic has a few ancillary features too...

```
---
some_variable: "yourvalue"
---
// access the value from the frontmatter within your script.
document.body.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "{{some_variable}}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Before adding front-matter (which fixed it for me, but breaks compatibility as noted by Samuel), try this first.

My JS file started out like this:

```
"use strict";

var filterView = {
```

Change it to this:

```
//A comment here helps Jekyll not get confused about file rendering
"use strict";

var filterView = {
```

In my case, I was only having problems with one of my JS files which was getting null characters added to it by Jekyll, and starting with "use strict" with nothing before it was the difference. I don't know if this will fix all causes of this problem but worth a shot.